# How can I 403 (forbid) POST against home "/" page in Apache2?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm getting about 40 requests per minute from what's apparently a botnet DoS where a "POST / HTTP/1.1" is being sent to the server and its enough to crash the web-app fronted by Apache2, but certainly not enough to crash the server nor Apache2.  I want to add a rewrite rule to basically 403 the POST action immediately in Apache, but I'm matching POST to all pages, not just "/".  Here's my code attempt so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ /$ [F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to match only /

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule ^ /$ [F]
```